# Inno Setup : Determine location of the actual setup executable

Tags: inno-setup

I need my inno setup application to save its location to the registry so my application can find it.  I need to be able to find the setup file and load it into my application's database so it can be extracted and used by other computers that connect to the database.  If a user downloads the setup file from the website instead of going through the normal update process then I won't know where he saved it to and opened it from - or at least that's what I'm trying to determine. Saving to the registry is no problem - getting the setup files location is what I'm missing.  Thanks.

Comment: OT: you can also include the *Modify* option to your *Add/Remove programs* item. That you can do if you set the [`AppModifyPath`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=setup_appmodifypath) directive value to the path where your installer will reside.

Answer (score 2):

Use `ExpandConstant('{srcexe}')`, as explained in the [documentation](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/topic_isxfunc_expandconstant.htm)

> Prototype:
>
> function ExpandConstant(const S: String): String;
>
> Description:
>
> Changes all constants in S to their values. For example, ExpandConstant('{srcexe}') is changed to the filename of Setup.
>
> An exception will be raised if there was an error expanding the constants.

Answer (score 0):

According to

http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=consts

{srcexe}  is what you are looking for.